# Mod Rewrite to remove file extension breaks when file has dashes in name

Tags: .htaccess

I am puzzled. I looked for answers to this question but I didn't find anything that I can actually relate.

I am using a simple mod rewrite script to get rid of **.php** extension and add a trailing slashon PHP files. I have a few simple PHP pages to deal with. Nothing earth shattering.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Suddenly I realized that if a file has a dash in the name the script breaks, and I get a 404 pahe not found,,,

```
www.domain.com/some-file-name.php
```

I get the same behavior on Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your regex. You are only allowing `lowercase letters` `([a-z]+).` You need to broaden your regex to include more characters. You can use `([\w-]+)` which includes letters and numbers and dashes.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

`\w` is shorthand which includes a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character. and then adding the dash afterwards allows dashes.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for the code and for explaining it.